# PHP trim() not working

Tags: php, trim

trim() is supposed to delete all whitespace.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Aufgabe 7</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $EingabeText = "L27Q6Z7123515756S234939Z942yZ33z02M665z2z-Z982493d64Zn96z52z34uZ-z72P72Z6H461034zP321Z23";
        echo "Zeichenkette vor Veränderung: " . $EingabeText . "<br>";
// a)
        $Anzahl_Z = 0;
        $Anzahl_z = 0;

        $Uebergabe = array( $EingabeText, $Anzahl_Z, $Anzahl_z );

        function ZundzLoeschenUndZaehlen( $MischArray )
        {
            $ZeichenkettenLaenge;
            $ZeichenkettenLaenge = strlen($MischArray[0]);
            echo "Zeichenkettenlänge: " . $ZeichenkettenLaenge . "<br>";
            for( $i = 0; $i < $ZeichenkettenLaenge - 1; $i++ )
            {
                if( $MischArray[0][$i] == "Z" )
                {
                    $MischArray[1] ++;
                }
                if( $MischArray[0][$i] == "z" )
                {
                    $MischArray[2] ++;
                }
            }
            //strpos(str, suche [,offset])
            $MischArray[0] = str_replace("Z", " ", $MischArray[0]);
            echo "Erstes str_replace: " . $MischArray[0] . "<br>";
            $MischArray[0] = str_replace("z", " ", $MischArray[0]);
            echo "Zweites str_replace: " . $MischArray[0] . "<br>";

            $ZeichenKette1;
            $ZeichenKette1 = $MischArray[0];
            var_dump($ZeichenKette1);

            echo "<br><br><br>" . (function_exists(trim)) . "<br><br><br>";
            //$ZeichenKette=trim($ZeichenKette," ");
            //$ZeichenKette1=trim($ZeichenKette1,' ');
            $ZeichenKette1 = trim($ZeichenKette1);
            $MischArray[0] = $ZeichenKette1;
            echo "Ohne Leerzeichen: " . $MischArray[0] . "<br>";

            /*
              //Removing spaces the hard way
              for();
              {
              string chunk_split ( string $body [, int $chunklen [, string $end]] )
              }
             */
            return $MischArray;
        }
        $Uebergabe = ZundzLoeschenUndZaehlen($Uebergabe);

//$Uebergabe[0];
//echo "Debug: ".$Anzahl_Z." ".$Anzahl_z."<br>";
        echo "Debug: " . $Uebergabe[1] . " " . $Uebergabe[2] . "<br>";
//echo "Zeichenkette nach der Veränderung: ".$EingabeText."<br>";
        echo "Zeichenkette nach der Veränderung: " . $Uebergabe[0] . "<br>";

// b)
// c)
//Zählen von Klein- und Großbuchstaben sowie Zahlen
//G=15 , K=11 , Z=60

        function GroßKleinZahlen( $Zeichenkette )
        {
            $ZL = strlen($Zeichenkette);
            $Großbuchstabe  = 0;
            $Kleinbuchstabe = 0;
            $Zahl           = 0;
            for( $i = 0; $i < $ZL; $i++ )
            {
                if( (($Zeichenkette[$i] >= "A") && ($Zeichenkette[$i] <= "Z") ) )
                {
                    $Großbuchstabe++;
                }

                if( (($Zeichenkette[$i] >= "a") && ($Zeichenkette[$i] <= "z") ) )
                {
                    $Kleinbuchstabe++;
                }

                if( (($Zeichenkette[$i] >= "0") && ($Zeichenkette[$i] <= "9") ) )
                {
                    $Zahl++;
                }
            }
            echo "Anzahl Großbuchstaben:" . $Großbuchstabe . "<br>";
            echo "Anzahl Kleinbuchstaben:" . $Kleinbuchstabe . "<br>";
            echo "Anzahl Zahlen:" . $Zahl . "<br>";
        }

        /* Großbuchstaben:
          (($var>="A") && ($var<="Z"))

          //Kleinbuchstaben:
          (($var>="a") && ($var<="z"))

          //Zahlen:
          (($var>="0") && ($var<="9"))
         */
        GroßKleinZahlen($EingabeText);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

all spaces deleted

none

Dunkel wars, der Mond schien helle

(sp. 19. Jh.)

Dunkel wars, der Mond schien helle,
schneebedeckt die grüne Flur,
als ein Wagen blitzeschnelle
langsam um die Ecke fuhr.

Drinnen saßen stehend Leute,
schweigend ins Gespräch vertieft,
als ein totgeschoss'ner Hase
auf der Sandbank Schlittschuh lief.

Und ein blondgelockter Jüngling
mit kohlrabenschwarzem Haar
saß auf einer blauen Kiste,
die rot angestrichen war.

Neben ihm 'ne alte Schachtel,
die kaum zählte sechzehn Jahr.
Und sie aß ein Butterbrot,
das mit Schmalz bestrichen war.

Droben auf dem Apfelbaume,
der sehr süße Birnen trug,
hing des Frühlings letzte Pflaume
und an Nüssen noch genug.

Und der Wagen fuhr im Trabe
rückwärts einen Berg hinauf.
Droben zog ein alter Rabe
grade eine Turmuhr auf.

Ringsumher herrscht tiefes Schweigen
und mit fürchterlichem Krach
spielen in des Grases Zweigen
zwei Kamele lautlos Schach.

Von der regennassen Straße
wirbelte der Staub empor.
und ein Junge bei der Hitze
mächtig an den Ohren fror.

Beide Hände in den Taschen
hielt er sich die Augen zu.
denn er konnte nicht ertragen,
wie nach Veilchen roch die Kuh.

Und zwei Fische liefen munter
durch das blaue Kornfeld hin.
Endlich ging die Sonne unter
und der graue Tag erschien.

Und das alles dichtet Goethe
als er in der Morgenröte
liegend auf dem Nachttopf saß
und dabei die Zeitung las.

Just for the shitty JS

"Must write useless words"()

The difference between concise and a lot of words.

Comment: [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) deletes all whitespace ___at the beginning or end of a string___; not all whitespace within the string

Comment: trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: `preg_replace('/\s/', '', $string)` would remove all whitespace. Could you post what you have and what is expected?

Comment: What you want is a `str_replace( " ", "", $Zeichenkette1);` (or a preg_replace() as @chris85 has stated. I don't know which one is faster)

Comment: Das Gedicht ist zwar Kunst, kann aber weg, oder? (That poem ist art, but may be gone, right?)

Comment: and a final sidenote: be carefull with special characters in variable/function-names, such as `ß` - Try to avoid them.

Comment: also for your second function (count uppercase/lowercase letters) a regex would be more suiteable

Comment: @Jeff, it appears that str_replace will be quicker (which I expect with regex)  https://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0 , though, I didn't test myself, I would expect that str_replace is also pretty slow, (link is also from 2007 as well, so a new test may be needed :) )

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` only deletes whitespace from begining or end of string.   if you want to delete all whitespace, you would have to do something like this, which replaces all occurances.

`function deleteAllWhitespace($string) {
    return str_replace(" ", "", $string);
}`

> `str_replace` will replace what ever the first property is (" ") with whatever the second property is ("") in the passed in third property.  In this case, we take all spaces, and replace them with nothing.

Things to note.  This could potentially slow down your site to do this str_replace, so use with caution.

ref: [String Replace Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

ref: [Trim Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)